# Complete list of what locale option changes in siunitx

Tags: siunitx

In `siunitx` you can specify a `locale` option. However the description in the [manual](https://ftp.agdsn.de/pub/mirrors/latex/dante/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx/siunitx.pdf) is not very specific:

> siunitx allows the user to switch between the typographic conventions
> of different (geographical) areas by using locales. Currently, the
> package is supplied with configurations for locales UK, US, DE
> (Germany), FR (French) and ZA (South Africa). The locale option is
> used to switch to a particular locale.

I am looking for a comprehensive detailed list of effects that choosing a locale in `siunitx` has. In particular I am interested in the German locale.

If possible the answer should say, which internal variable are changed to which value by choosing a particular locale (for example `output-decimal-marker` from `.` to `,`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The locale key sets these three things (also for the other languages, only with different values, you can look up the details by searching in the sty):

```
    locale / DE .meta:n =
      {
        exponent-product      = \cdot ,
        inter-unit-product    = \,    ,
        output-decimal-marker = { , }
      } ,
```

Comment: Thanks, additionally it does introduce some translations: https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/blob/main/siunitx-locale.dtx; Just found it out by myself a few minutes after posting the question. But I was to slow to answer my own question :-).